# App goes to home page on click in android

Tags: android

I am working on app in which i get the services on button click but when i click on buuton and services start coming from server my app changes its screen to home screen in nexus one and once the services get downloaded from server , next page of app gets displayed . But i want till the time services get downloaded from server app of app should be on same page .Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

may be you should use focus listener